# IE7 div position fixed

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a div which needs to fill out the height of the browser's viewport,but still says in the same position when the user scrolls the web page up and down. position: fixed; does this, but I am unable to use it as it's making the overflow scroll bar of the div jerky and slow. Is there an position or method that I can use so for example I currently have:

```
div.panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 36px; 
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #636362;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0px;
  width: 290px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with "jerky and slow", because all scrollbars act the same. This is how I would resolve your issue:

HTML:

```
<div class="fixed">I'm fixed!</div>
<p>Rest of page</p>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  /* make sure the page is at least height of viewport */
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* because the fixed div is no part of the flow, 
     make sure it is not overlapping the webpage  */
  padding: 0 0 0 100px;
}
.fixed {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  /* only vertical-scrolling, but can be changed of course */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[JSfiddled Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/LAYHX/)

Works in at least IE7, IE8 and Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for that, I think I solved the issue using your code as a starting point. It was to do with some jQuery library that I was using and it was injecting extra styles in IE. By slow, I meant the scrollbars had a delay in responsiveness.

Comment: Is the delay-issue fixed this way? I never really experienced a slow scrollbar, only when my Windows processes are going berserk and my cursor hits an fps of below 1. Switching to Linux soon anyway...